# Distinguish among WEP-40 (WEP-64) and WEP-104 (WEP-128) in Linux

Tags: linux, openwrt

Let's see if someone can help me with this problem that is getting me nuts. My problem is as follows:

I am trying to identify which security/cipher protocol is being used by the network I am connected to. Particularly speaking I want to be able to know if the network I am connected to is either using WEP-40 or WEP-104 in a Linux system (openWRT).

I have tried the following options but I am only able to distinguish among WEP, WPA and WPA2, not any of the particular versions of the aforementioned protocols.

- nm-tool
- wpa_supplicant: scan, get_capability proto, get_capability group
- iwlist wlan0 encryption

However, none of these give me a clear output, other than WEP.

As a side requirement, if possible of course, it would be appreciated if the proposed solution was, so to say, lightweight, since the desired functionality is to be added to an embedded system with only 16MB of flash.

As an idea, I believe wpa_supplicant should/must have a way to identify the version of the protocol in question, but I was not able to identify it in http://w1.fi/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-devel.pdf nor https://w1.fi/wpa_supplicant/devel/ctrl_iface_page.html.

Thanks you very much in advance for your help.